# C++ separate function print

Tags: c++, function, object, printing, syntax

I'm trying to write a test function for print. Everything compiles fine but why does it not print? what am i doing wrong? can someone please help me out? thanks

oneLine.cpp

```
#include "oneLine.h"
#include <iostream>


OneLine::OneLine() {

cout << "test";

}

OneLine::~OneLine() {

cout << "~test";

}
```

oneLine.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class OneLine {

    OneLine();
    ~OneLine();
    void breakLine();
    void printReverse();
    istream &readLine(istream& is);
    string returnLine();

private:
    string oneLine;
    char **words;
    int wordCount;
    void resetLine();

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "oneLine.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {

OneLine oLine();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up "[most] vexing parse."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a function declaration:

```
OneLine oLine(); // declaration of a function returning a OneLine object
```

To default construct a `OneLine` object, you need

```
OneLine oLine;
```

or, in C++11, you can also use `{}`:

```
OneLine oLine{};
```

Next, as @POW points out in the comments, your default constructor and destructor have to be made `public`. Currently they are `private`.

As an aside, note that [`using namespace std` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), especially in header files.

Comment: and constructor & destructor needs to be in `public` section, for this case

Comment: @P0W Good catch! I added it to my answer.

Comment: i change "OneLine oLine();" to "OneLine oLine;" in the main.cpp but it doesnt even compile. what do you mean?

Comment: @NewFile it could be because your constructor and destructor are `private`.

Comment: only the variable names in oneLine.h are private the functions are natually set to public right?

Comment: @NewFile As it stands, *everything* is `private` in `OneLine`.

Comment: how do i work with that? sorry im really confused now

Comment: @NewFile just put `public:` before the constructor. Everything until the `private:` will be public.